# Battery indicator stuck at 98% percentage

Tags: indicator, power-management, battery

Ubuntu 13.10 64-bit, used to work fine but lately battery applet with percentage says 98% at boot but doesn't drain (though obviously battery is draining).

How can I reboot the applet/make it work normally? Tried to end session, suspend, reboot...
didn't work. It, for some weeks, works fine, and for some others like this. I'm upset (being an average user without any special knowledge, just type in the console what others more capable say).

I'm on an ACER Aspire Timeline U Intel® Core™ i3-2367M CPU @ 1.40GHz × 4, Intel® Sandybridge Mobile graphics.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Tried: sudo apt-get purge indicator-power then sudo apt-get install indicator-power  without success.

Comment: It ran out of battery! Let me totally down, then charge from 0% and now it's workin'. Need to say before, at frozen 98% it said battery time left was "10:01" now points "5:37", "6:44" (minutes later) and "5:06". Seems recaculating. I don't have a clue what happened here...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is due to a battery hardware problem